# Issues importing gtstreamer in python

Tags: python, gstreamer

I've run the windows installer, but I'm unsure how to begin using gtstreamer. The tutorials I've read simply instruct me to install the package and then import the module `pygst`, but when I try that I get an `ImportError: No module named pygst`.

I've searched my C drive. and it seems to have installed to `/program files/OSSBuild/GStreamer`, but I'm unsure how to access it. To date, every module I've installed automatically adds itself to `lib/site packages` *or* has the `setup.py` file. This one does not, so it's a bit foreign to me.

How do I get up and running..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try editing the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include that directory (separate the paths by semicolons). Example: Add `C:\program files\OSSBuild\GStreamer` to the end `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\other-python-files-etc;C:\program files\OSSBuild\GStreamer`

Per this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/1124529

Also, you may want to check to make sure that in that GStreamer folder there is a file called `pygst.py` since that is how the module will look. If not, you may have downloaded the wrong thing.